# Trigger apps script through Cloud function

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to trigger apps script through cloud function. My cloud function is linked a bucket so when new file is inserted to bucket; it's triggered and it call document ai to extract data from file and save data to big query table. After storing data to big query table, it makes http call to trigger my apps script.
Cloud function runs fine and I can see in the log: Google Apps Script Response Status Code: 200
But no entry in apps script log.
When tested manually, my apps script work fine, produce the expected result.
Please these my cloud function and apps script code, I need your help:

Cloud Funtion

```
import os
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import documentai
from google.cloud import storage
import json
import requests

project_id = 'myproject001'
location = 'eu'
mime_type = 'application/pdf'
processor_id = '111aaaasdfvgetrt11'
bucket_name = 'p2p_docai_extraction'
dataset_id = 'p2p_docai_data'
table_id = 'invoices_data'
apps_script_url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/carrefour.com/s/zsdcvffxNPdscvbnnzo3z27CT1AA3Ocgnru7Pgl_ujikklmnfr-Mg/exec'

def trigger_apps_script(file_name):
    # Include the file name as a query parameter in the URL
    apps_script_url_with_params = f'{apps_script_url}&file_name={file_name}'

    try:
        # Send an HTTP GET request to trigger the Google Apps Script function
        response = requests.get(apps_script_url_with_params)
        print('Google Apps Script Response Content:', response.text)  # Log the response content
        print('Google Apps Script Response Status Code:', response.status_code)  # Log the response status code

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print('Google Apps Script executed successfully')
        else:
            print('Error executing Google Apps Script:', response.status_code)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error executing Google Apps Script:', str(e))




def parse_to_bigquery(event, context):  # Level 0
    file = event  # Level 1
    print(f"Processing file: {file['name']}.")  # Level 1

    local_path = "/tmp/" + file['name']  # Level 1

    storage_client = storage.Client()  # Level 1
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)  # Level 1
    blob = bucket.blob(file['name'])  # Level 1
    blob.download_to_filename(local_path)  # Level 1

    opts = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{location}-documentai.googleapis.com")  # Level 1
    client = documentai.DocumentProcessorServiceClient(client_options=opts)  # Level 1
    name = client.processor_path(project_id, location, processor_id)   # Level 1
    
    with open(local_path, "rb") as image:   # Level 1
        image_content = image.read()   # Level 2
    
    raw_document = documentai.RawDocument(content=image_content, mime_type=mime_type)   # Level 1
    request = documentai.ProcessRequest(name=name, raw_document=raw_document)   # Level 1
    result = client.process_document(request=request)   # Level 1
    document = result.document   # Level 1

    row_to_bq = {
        "file": file['name'],
        "amount_due": None,
        "amount_dueConfidence": None,
        "amount_paid_since_last_invoice": None,
        "amount_paid_since_last_invoiceConfidence": None,
        "carrier": None,
        "carrierConfidence": None,
        "currency": None,
        "currencyConfidence": None,
        "currency_exchange_rate": None,
        "currency_exchange_rateConfidence": None,
        "customer_tax_id": None,
        "customer_tax_idConfidence": None,
        "delivery_date": None,
        "delivery_dateConfidence": None,
        "due_date": None,
        "due_dateConfidence": None,
        "freight_amount": None,
        "freight_amountConfidence": None,
        "invoice_date": None,
        "invoice_dateConfidence": None,
        "invoice_id": None,  
        "invoice_idConfidence": None,
        "invoice_type": None,
        "invoice_typeConfidence": None,
        "line_item": None,
        "line_itemConfidence": None,
        "net_amount": None,
        "net_amountConfidence": None,
        "payment_terms": None,
        "payment_termsConfidence": None,
        "purchase_order": None,
        "purchase_orderConfidence": None,
        "receiver_address": None,
        "receiver_addressConfidence": None,
        "receiver_email": None,
        "receiver_emailConfidence": None,
        "receiver_name": None,
        "receiver_nameConfidence": None,
        "receiver_phone": None,
        "receiver_phoneConfidence": None,
        "receiver_tax_id": None,
        "receiver_tax_idConfidence": None,
        "receiver_website": None,
        "receiver_websiteConfidence": None,
        "remit_to_address": None,
        "remit_to_addressConfidence": None,
        "remit_to_name": None,
        "remit_to_nameConfidence": None,
        "ship_from_address": None,
        "ship_from_addressConfidence": None,
        "ship_from_name": None,
        "ship_from_nameConfidence": None,
        "ship_to_address": None,
        "ship_to_addressConfidence": None,
        "ship_to_name": None,
        "ship_to_nameConfidence": None,
        "supplier_address": None,
        "supplier_addressConfidence": None,
        "supplier_email": None,
        "supplier_emailConfidence": None,
        "supplier_iban": None,
        "supplier_ibanConfidence": None,
        "supplier_name": None,
        "supplier_nameConfidence": None,
        "supplier_payment_ref": None,
        "supplier_payment_refConfidence": None,
        "supplier_phone": None,
        "supplier_phoneConfidence": None,
        "supplier_registration": None,
        "supplier_registrationConfidence": None,
        "supplier_tax_id": None,
        "supplier_tax_idConfidence": None,
        "total_amount": None,
        "total_amountConfidence": None,
        "total_tax_amount": None,
        "total_tax_amountConfidence": None,
        "vat": None,
        "vatConfidence": None,
        "amount": None,
        "amountConfidence": None,
        "category_code": None,
        "category_codeConfidence": None,
        "tax_amount": None,
        "tax_amountConfidence": None,
        "tax_rate": None,
        "tax_rateConfidence": None,
    }   # Level 1

    entity_row = []   # Level 1
    line = []   # Level 1
    for entity in document.entities:   # Level 1
        if entity.type_ == "line_item":   # Level 2
            item = {   # Level ...
                "name": entity.type_, 
                "content": entity.mention_text,   
                "confidence": f"{entity.confidence:.0%}"   
            }   
            line.append(item)   # ...2
        row_to_bq[entity.type_] = entity.mention_text   
        row_to_bq[entity.type + 'Confidence'] = f"{entity.confidence:.0%}"   

    row_to_bq['line_item'] = str(line)   # ...2
    
    client = bigquery.Client()   # ...2
    table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)   
    table = client.get_table(table_ref)   # ...2

    rows_to_insert = [row_to_bq]   # ...2

    errors = client.insert_rows_json(table, rows_to_insert)  
    trigger_apps_script(file['name'])   # ...2 (Call to the function defined above)
    return 'Processing completed', 200
```

Apps Script

```
function doGet(e) {
  // Use getParameters to extract query parameters
  var file_name = e.parameter.file_name;
  var invoice_id = e.parameter.invoice_id || null;
  Logger.log("Received parameters:");
  Logger.log("file_name: " + file_name);
  Logger.log("invoice_id: " + invoice_id);

  // Fetch data from BigQuery
  var projectId = 'myproject001';
  var datasetId = 'p2p_docai_data';
  var tableId = 'invoices_data';

  // Encode the file_name parameter to make it safe for the SQL query
  var encodedFileName = encodeURIComponent(file_name);

  var query = 'SELECT ' +
    'file, invoice_id, invoice_date, net_amount, total_amount, receiver_address, receiver_name, ' +
    'receiver_phone, supplier_name, supplier_address, supplier_email, delivery_date, supplier_iban, ' +
    'total_tax_amount, currency, category_code, ' +
    'JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(line_item, \'$.unit\') AS unit, ' +
    'JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(line_item, \'$.content\') AS description ' +
    'FROM `' + projectId + '.' + datasetId + '.' + tableId + '`, ' +
    'UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(line_item, \'$\')) AS item ' +
    'WHERE file = "' + encodedFileName + '"' +
    (invoice_id ? ' AND invoice_id = "' + invoice_id + '"' : '') +
    'GROUP BY file, invoice_id, invoice_date, net_amount, description, receiver_address, receiver_name, ' +
    'receiver_phone, supplier_address, supplier_email, supplier_name, unit, delivery_date, supplier_iban, total_amount, ' +
    'total_tax_amount, currency, category_code';

  var request = {
    query: query,
    useLegacySql: false
  };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, projectId);
  var data = queryResults.rows;

  if (!data || data.length === 0) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("No data found for the given parameters.");
  }

  // Open the template Google Sheet
  var templateSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1AaajZuGdddddddddddQuy0U_jhkPc4');
  var newSpreadsheet = templateSpreadsheet.copy(file_name);
  newSpreadsheet.setName(file_name);

  // Open the second sheet in the new spreadsheet
  var sheet2 = newSpreadsheet.getSheets()[1]; // Index 0 is the first sheet

  // Populate specific cells in page 2 with data from the query
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var rowData = data[i].f;
    var rowIndex = i + 7;
      Logger.log("Row " + rowIndex + ":");
      Logger.log("receiver_name: " + decodeURIComponent(rowData[6].v));
      Logger.log("delivery_date: " + decodeURIComponent(rowData[10].v));

    // Populate specific cells in page 2 with data from the query result
    sheet2.getRange('C' + rowIndex).setValue(decodeURIComponent(rowData[6].v)); // receiver_name
    sheet2.getRange('D' + rowIndex).setValue(decodeURIComponent(rowData[10].v)); // delivery_date
    sheet2.getRange('E' + rowIndex).setValue(decodeURIComponent(rowData[5].v)); // receiver_address
    sheet2.getRange('F' + rowIndex).setValue(decodeURIComponent(rowData[6].v)); // receiver_name
    sheet2.getRange('G' + rowIndex).setValue(decodeURIComponent(rowData[10].v)); // supplier_address
    sheet2.getRange('N' + rowIndex).setValue(decodeURIComponent(rowData[5].v)); // currency
  }

  // Create a download link for the new Google Sheet
  var newSpreadsheetId = newSpreadsheet.getId();
  var downloadLink = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + newSpreadsheetId + "/export?format=xlsx";
  
  Logger.log("Download link: " + downloadLink);

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(downloadLink);
}
```

When new file is inserted into bucket cloud function try to make an http call to trigger apps script but it's not working even I see "Google Apps Script executed successfully" .

Comment: In your situation, can I ask you about the details of the setting of your Web Apps? In this case, can I ask you about the details of the setting of `Execute as:` and `Who has access to the app:`? I guess that in your situation, the access token might be required to be used for requesting the Web Apps.

Comment: Hi,
Please find bellow the details:
Execute as: Me
Who has access to the app: Cloud Function (user put file only in a given bucket)

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your situation, how about including the access token in the request header or the query parameter?

Comment: Yes I tried adding token in my cloud function but I got the same result

YOUR_API_KEY='ABCD-kvfgbBUqrbnhhjttttttttGjh-rtg5'

# Replace 'YOUR_WEB_APP_URL' with the actual URL of your deployed Google Apps Script web app
apps_script_url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/carrefour.com/s/AKfycbxNPlyVLWvQKJx1wZNKrPoSXbLzo3z27CT1AA3Ocgnru7Pglz_A465SKR4XYqPRy-Mg/exec'
#apps_script_url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/mydomain.com/s/gggggggggXjjfIwyaiVp325nyy7rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrUJT6dQ_jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj/exec?key=' + YOUR_API_KEY

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand your current situation.

Comment: You don't have to apologize, it's my english which is not good. Thank you for replying.
In short when new file is inserted into bucket, cloud function try to make an http call to trigger apps script but it's not working even I can see "Google Apps Script executed successfully" in cloud function log .